# Не получается настроить ingress-nginx

Tags: kubernetes

Всем привет.
Разворачиваю кластер куба в виртуальной среде(kvm)..

имею 3 ноды( мастер воркер воркер) и серую сеть

развернул кластер средствами kubeadm

скачал kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml

развернул под и пытаюсь его примонстрятчить к ингесс-нжингсу ..

сервис под видит, ингрес под видит, а попасть на него не могу

Answer (score 2):

> развернул под и пытаюсь его примонстрятчить к ингесс-нжингсу

нужно делать деплоймент -> сервис с `type: NodePort`

```
kubectl get ingress
```

в ответ будет что-то типа:

```
NAME                    CLASS    HOSTS                  ADDRESS      PORTS   AGE
ingress-name            <none>   какой-то хост          какой-то ip  80      7d18h
```

если локально то в /etc/hosts добавить строчку

```
какой-то ip  какой-то хост
```

если же на серверах то, скорее всего, нужно домен прикрутить к `какой-то ip`

но это всего лишь догадка, которая может быть не верная.